# how to run code after process termination

Tags: java

is there any way to run code after process termination?like from task manager...
i tried `Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook()`, but its triggers only from `System.exit()`...
also i tried second thread to keep track if main thread is alive but it also didnt helped...
my friend told me that i should make dll that checks for process is alive every second and inject that dll into somewhere...
but i dont know how to make dll`s and how to inject them...so...i think there must be another way)

Comment: You "could" - monitor the running processes and take action when the one you are watching disappears.  This will require you to go a JNI/JNA path, as there aren't any "real" options available for doing this natively.  You could execute the process from another program and "wait till it dies".  This is a common enough solution

Comment: @MadProgrammer good suggestion...but i forgot to specify...current process,where java is running...

Comment: @MadProgrammer No need for JNI/JNA. Have one Java program run another and use [`waitFor()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor--), then do whatever followup is needed.

Comment: @Andreas As I said - but, it would depend on what the OP needs